# PHP Countdown time string formatter function

Tags: php, string, time

I have a php function that I have created it formats time that has elapsed and it takes a normal timestamp as input parameter. There is no physical problem and it works as expected, my question is, is there a way to simplify it?:

**PHP**

```
function time_elapsed_string($difference)
{       

    //Days
    $days = round(($difference / 86400), 2);

    //Hours
    $hours = floor($difference / 3600);
    if($hours >= 24) {
        $remainderHours = fmod($hours, 24); // Get the remainder from the days.

        if ($remainderHours < 10) {
            $remainderHours = '0' . $remainderHours;
        }
    } else {
        $remainderHours = $hours; 
        $days = 0;


        if ($remainderHours < 10) {
            $remainderHours = '0' . $hours;
        }
    }   

    //Minutes
    $mins = floor($difference / 60);

    if ($mins >= 60){
        $remainderMins = fmod($mins, 60);

        if ($remainderMins < 10) {
            $remainderMins = '0' . $remainderMins;
        }
    } else {
        $remainderMins = $mins;
        if ($remainderMins < 10) {
            $remainderMins = '0' . $remainderMins;
        }
    }

    //Seconds
    $seconds = floor($difference);
    if($seconds >= 60) {
        $remainderSeconds = fmod($seconds, 60); 

        if ($remainderSeconds < 10) {
            $remainderSeconds = '0' . $remainderSeconds;
        }
    } else {
        $remainderSeconds = $seconds;
        if ($remainderSeconds < 10) {
            $remainderSeconds = '0' . $remainderSeconds;
        }
    }

    //Format day due to days being reset to 0 format in hours fuction
    $days = (floor($days) < 10 ? ('0' . floor($days)) : floor($days));

    return  $days . ':' . $remainderHours . ':' . $remainderMins     . ':' . $remainderSeconds;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can most likely do it in a much clearner way using a `DateInterval` object: http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php